# Extract files from *.gz extension

Tags: java

I have successfully extracted `*.gz` from `*.tgz` and now I have no idea how to actually extract final files from `*.tgz`.

There are some options using custom packages but that's not an option for me, **I need to use standard Java packages only**.

What I tried is using same function that I use for `*.tgz` for `*.gz` but it doesn't work.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format 1.gz

Here is function that is extracting `*.tgz` files.

```
public String ExtractFile(String path) {
    try {
        File newFile = new File(this.getFullPathWithoutExtension(path) + ".gz");

        GZIPInputStream gStream;
        FileOutputStream outStream;
        try (FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(path)) {
            gStream = new GZIPInputStream(fileStream);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = gStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
        gStream.close();
        outStream.close();

        newFile.createNewFile();

        return newFile.getPath();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

TL;DR; `*.tgz` files extracted to `*.gz` files, however `*.gz` files cannot be extracted.

Comment: When you say "What I tried is using same function that I use for *.tgz for *.gz but it doesn't work." do you mean you tried performing the same decompression twice, effectively?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yea, same function for file that is already extracted. Because on file browser it said "GZip archive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.tgz` file wouldn't normally be extracted to a `.gz` file - it would be extracted to a `.tar` file. (A `.gz` file is gzipped; a `.tar` file is an uncompressed archive containing multiple files; a `.tgz` is a `.tar` file that's then been gzipped - you've already "undone" the gzipping.)

I don't *think* there's anything within Java's standard libraries to handle tar files - so you'll either have to revisit your "I can't use anything not in the standard library" decision or reimplement it yourself. The [file format is easily available](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) if you decide to do that.

Comment: Oh, so basically I set wrong extension when I extract them? I should set them as `tar` files first?

Comment: @Steve: Yes - although that won't really help you much. You could have extracted the data to any filename you want; you've still got to then find something which will handle tar files.

Comment: Yea, okey. I just used commons from apache and it's working fine. Thanks.